# Intellij dynamic classpath loading fails: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, scala, jvm

Using Intellij 15.0.3 on a Scala project, I am unable to run my scala console.

I added one too many dependencies and Intellij told me "Command line is too long. In order to reduce its length classpath file can be used.Would you like to enable classpath file mode for all run configurations of your project?" I enabled it, whihc sets dynamic.classpath=true in an xml file.

Now when I try to run the console I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: @vm_params
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.loadMainClassWithOldCustomLoader(CommandLineWrapper.java:174)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:38)
```

Googling around I didn't see anyone else have this problem. This feature seems like it should "just work". Is there something else I have to do do get intellij to make a classpath file and send the path to the VM?